# waitForElementVisible in selenium not working in MicrosoftEdge

Tags: javascript, selenium, microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js

I'm having trouble with the function that waits for elements to be visible when running the selenium tests in MicrosoftEdge. Especially when an element is on top of another element. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is there a javascript function that I can use to make sure that the user sees the element and can click on it?

Here's what I'm using for now

```
   function waitForElementDisplay (selector, time) {
            if (document.querySelector(selector) != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (timeLimit < timeSince) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                timeSince += time;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    waitForElementDisplay(selector, time, timeLimit, timeSince);
                }, time);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, selenium some times does have problems. Never worked with Edge, but had similar issues with other browsers.

What I typically do is to write a retry wrapper and then use
"document.getElementById"(or something) inside the script executor to get element reference inside the script executor. I try for a few times with X seconds delay.

Following example in java shows how I am waiting for some element to become accessible in DOM. (I am using cucumberJVM)

```
@When("^questionnaire response is loaded$")
public void questionnaire_response_is_loaded() throws Throwable {

    Predicate<WebDriver> isLoaded = new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            Object obj = ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
                    "return (!document.getElementById('idNotification'))"
            );
            // if element is present the result will turn false, so we have to negate it
            return !((Boolean) obj);
        }
    };

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserDriver.getCurrentDriver(), 10);
    wait.until(isLoaded);
}
```

Comment: do you have example codE?

Answer (score 0):

The method `waitForElementVisible` only checks that the element is rendered with a size and opacity superior to 0. It doesn't check whether the element is visible by a human eye or not.

You could use this JavaScript function to check if an element is visible and clickable:

```js
function isClickable(element) {
  var doc = element.ownerDocument || document,
    win = doc.defaultView || window,
    rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elemAt = doc.elementFromPoint(rect.left + (rect.width >> 1), rect.top + (rect.height >> 1));

  for (var e = elemAt; e; e = e.parentElement) {
    if (e === element) return !elemAt.disabled && win.getComputedStyle(elemAt, null).getPropertyValue('pointer-events') !== 'none';
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that it will return false if the element in not scrolled into the view. So you may need to call `element.scrollIntoView()` first.